# QWebEngineView fit content horizontally to screen

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I am trying to make a new software with a browser as a widget.

This is the code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
        self.browser.resize(510,600)
        self.browser.setZoomFactor(0)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

The code works perfectly fine and the size needs to be constant as the values given in the code. The problem is: In that small window I cannot see the whole web page like if I search for "who is the president of America" I have to scroll all the way to the right to view the whole content.

I want to view the content as if the browser is in its full size and I view the content as a regular browser maximised.

Comment: use  `self.showMaximized()`

Comment: You want zoomIn or zoomOut to be applied so that the scrollbars disappear, am I correct?

Comment: @JashSmith Is it just *horizontal scrolling* that you're concerned about? Because (depending on screen-size and resolution) the fonts will have to become really tiny to fit the *entire* content of most webpages. I just tried zooming out on the current webpage with my desktop browser and it quickly becomes completely unreadable on my screen.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, I am trying to remove the vertical scroll and fit the web page to the screen; for example I want the browser to show like a browsing app used in phones.

Comment: @JashSmith "fit the web page to the screen" depends on a lot of factors: the default system (or browser) font, the device's DPI, and the design support from the website (if it's *responsive* or not). Also, please be more precise with your terminology: "fit the screen" and "fit the window" (which is what you probably want, and the fact that the window occupies the whole screen is ininfluential) are two completely different things.